# What spreads faster - temperature or relative humidity?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, humidity

Let's say you open a window. There is difference in temperature and relative humidity between inside and outside air. Which room quantity will equalize faster with the outside - temperature or humidity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humidity will equalize mainly by convection (and somewhat with diffusion) whereas temperature, along with convection, will also use conduction and radiation. So my guess is temperature will equalize faster.

Comment: The thermal diffusivity of air is 19 mm^2/sec, while the molecular diffusivity of water vapor in air is 0.0016 mm^2/sec.

Comment: @ChetMiller you should expand on that and post as an answer. The relative diffusivity (probably slightlly temperature - dependent) of H2O vapor is the important feature here.